# Get data from product using XPATH nodes and insert them into table

Tags: php, html, xpath

I'm trying to get product data from the external web site and insert them in special table - every found node element need to be imported in appropriate column for the product in the product table!

It's working fine for finding 1 product attribute and inserting it into table:

```
$product_names = $xpath->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' product_description ')]/div/h3/a");
        if (!is_null($product_names)) {
            foreach ($product_names as $product_name) {
                $nodes = $product_name->childNodes;
                foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                    $import_product = 'INSERT INTO product_table (id, product_name) values ("","' . preg_replace('~\\s+\\S+$~', "", strip_tags(trim($node->nodeValue))) . '")';
                    mysql_query($import_supralift_name);
                }
            }
        }
```

but products have many attributes, so, I'm trying to get this product attribute (which is in 1 html element, so I need to split it in array an use for different attributes):

```
$types = $xpath->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' product_description ')]/div/a/p");
        if (!is_null($types)) {
            foreach ($types as $type) {
                $nodes = $type->childNodes;
                foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                    list($typee,$power_unit) = explode(' / ', $node->nodeValue);
                    $import_type = 'INSERT INTO product_table (id, type, power_unit) values ("", "' . strip_tags(trim($typee)) . '", "' . strip_tags(trim($power_unit)) . '")';
                    mysql_query($import_type);
                }
            }
        }
```

In short - I need to get 3 product attributes (of course, they're more, just want to figure out what would be the best solution to get it working) from external web site and insert it into my data base like:

```
product_name_1 product_type_1 $power_unit_1
...
product_name_X product_type_X $power_unit_X
```

So far I tried to put second xpath part in first foreach, but it does not work as need...
Should I try to make array with xpath nodes (like $prodcuts=array(firstXpathNode, secondXpathNode etc..) and work in such way or there is better and more correct solution for this?

In advance - TXN for any tips...

EDITED:
Here are sample HTML from what I'm trying to get the data, this is for the product (each product has this html for displaying data):

```
<div class="single_product">
    <div data-section="featured_image">
        <a title="Unique_String" href="#">
            <div style="" data-section="image" class="image_in_fixed_ratio_wrapper">
                <div class="inner visible">
                    <img alt="Unique_String" src="image1.jpg" class="" style="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div data-section="data">
        <div class="product_description">
            <div data-field="description_detail">
                <h3><a title="Unique_String" href="#">Product Name<div class="donotwantthistoinclude">New</div></a></h3>
                <a title="Unique_String" href="#"><p>Product Type / Product Power Unit</p></a>
                <div data-field="price">
                    <a title="Unique_String" href="#">5,000</a>
                </div>
                <div data-field="description">
                    <a title="Unique_String" href="#">
                        <span>Height (mm)</span> 2344
                 |
                                <span>Other attribute 1</span> Duplex
                 |
                                <span>Other attribute 2 (kg)</span>  1400
                 |
                                <span>Other attribute 3</span> 2014

                                 | <span>Other attribute X (h)</span> 772
                        <br><span>Location</span> D - 85716
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It might help if you post some sample data.

Comment: yes, I edited my thread with sample html which contains product info!

Comment: Anything unclear in my answer below?

Comment: unfortunatelly seems not working...  The problem is that product names are not unique, but found that there are a elements which titles are unique (contains unique id there included in brackets () ). I edited source html to be clear! What I would like to get from this html into my database: image url (has parent element a with unique title), Product name (has parent element a with unique title), Product Type / Product Power Unit (has parent element a with unique title) and all attributes in div data-field=description (has parent element a with unique title) each attribute in seperate column!

Comment: I made it working for these 2 parameters I need fro guiding, but somehow it inserts twice 1 product... For other attributes that I need (in div data-field=description element) and image url I would need additional xpath with foreach?

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier, it's been a bit busy. I am working on a fiddle for you. I've mostly implemented it in Javascript now, due to...well...reasons, but I'll get working on a PHP translation for you if you need it. I'll post a link to the Javascript fiddle for reference when I get on my computer, and perhaps just the flow and xpath queries is enough.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you separate out the product name in the first `foreach` into a variable, you can build a relative XPATH based on the product name. I'm assuming the product names are unique on the page. Then the second XPATH finds the product name on the page and walks a bit further down the elements. Now, there will guaranteed be better XPATH queries to write to do that, I just haven't got that skill level myself, but I do give you one way to do it.

The flow will therefore be something like:

for each product, get the name, insert name into new query to get that particular product's type and power unit, parse the variables, insert into DB.

## WARNING

You are using dangerous and outdated SQL. Please use the newer mysqli_* or PDO libraries to access the database using prepared statements. I did NOT update your code to reflect that, it's easy to Google.

I did however insert `product_name` in your existing SQL to illustrate how all 3 fields are gathered.

```
$product_names = $xpath->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' product_description ')]/div/h3/a");
if (!is_null($product_names)) {
    foreach ($product_names as $product_name) {
        $nodes = $product_name->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            $productName = preg_replace('~\\s+\\S+$~', "", strip_tags(trim($node->nodeValue)));
            $xpath_relative = sprintf("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' product_description ')]/div/h3/a[contains(text(),'%s')]/../../a/p",$productName);

            $types = $xpath->query($xpath_relative);
            if (!is_null($types)) {
                foreach ($types as $type) {
                    $types_nodes = $type->childNodes;
                    foreach ($types_nodes as $type_node) {
                        list($typee,$power_unit) = explode(' \'', $type_node->nodeValue);

                        // WARNING!!! SQL INJECTION BELOW!!!
                        $import_type = 'INSERT INTO product_table (id, type, power_unit, product_name) values ("", "' . strip_tags(trim($typee)) . '", "' . strip_tags(trim($power_unit)) . '", "' . $product_name . '")';
                        mysql_query($import_type);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### EDIT #2

I have taken your code and run with it in a PHP Fiddle with the following result. I've also optimised the XPATH queries based on the provided structure, as well as provide a suggestion on using PDO. Just fill in more attributes as needed. I'll leave you with the entire code, including the DOM and XPATH initialisation I have used so you can fiddle with it yourself.

```
<pre><?php

$domDoc = <<<EOF
<div class="single_product">
    <div data-section="featured_image">
        <a title="Unique_String" href="#">
            <div style="" data-section="image" class="image_in_fixed_ratio_wrapper">
                <div class="inner visible">
                    <img alt="Unique_String" src="image1.jpg" class="" style="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div data-section="data">
        <div class="product_description">
            <div data-field="description_detail">
                <h3><a title="Unique_String" href="#">Product Name<div class="donotwantthistoinclude">New</div></a></h3>
                <a title="Unique_String" href="#"><p>Product Type / Product Power Unit</p></a>
                <div data-field="price">
                    <a title="Unique_String" href="#">5,000</a>
                </div>
                <div data-field="description">
                    <a title="Unique_String" href="#">
                        <span>Height (mm)</span> 2344
                 |
                                <span>Other attribute 1</span> Duplex
                 |
                                <span>Other attribute 2 (kg)</span>  1400
                 |
                                <span>Other attribute 3</span> 2014

                                 | <span>Other attribute X (h)</span> 772
                        <br /><span>Location</span> D - 85716
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
EOF;
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML($domDoc);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

$products = [];

$productUniqueQuery = "//div[@data-field='description_detail']/h3/a/@title";

$productUniqueNodes = $xpath->query($productUniqueQuery);
if (!is_null($productUniqueNodes)) {
    foreach ($productUniqueNodes as $productUniqueNode) {
        $product = [];
        $product["unique"] = $productUniqueNode->nodeValue;

        $productNameQuery = sprintf("//h3/a[@title='%s']/text()",$product["unique"]);
        $productNameNodes = $xpath->query($productNameQuery);
        $product["name"] = $productNameNodes[0]->nodeValue;

        $productImageQuery = sprintf("//img[@alt='%s']/@src",$product["unique"]);
        $productImageNodes = $xpath->query($productImageQuery);
        $product["imageURL"] = $productImageNodes[0]->nodeValue;

        $productTypeQuery = sprintf("//a[@title='%s']/p/text()",$product["unique"]);
        $productTypeNodes = $xpath->query($productTypeQuery);
        list($product["type"], $product["powerUnit"]) = explode(" / ", $productTypeNodes[0]->nodeValue);

        $productDescriptionQuery = sprintf("//div[@data-field='description']/a[@title='%s']/child::node()",$product["unique"]);
        $productDescriptionNodes = $xpath->query($productDescriptionQuery);
        $description = "";
        foreach ($productDescriptionNodes as $productDescriptionNode) {
            $nodeText = preg_replace("/\s*\|/","",trim($productDescriptionNode->nodeValue));
            if($nodeText == "" || $productDescriptionNode->nodeType === 3){
                continue;
            }

            $product[$nodeText] = preg_replace("/\s*\|/","",trim($productDescriptionNode->nextSibling->nodeValue));
        }
        $products[$product["unique"]] = $product;
    }
}


try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DBNAME;port=3306","USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO product_table (unique, name, type, power_unit, attr1) values (:unique, :name, :type, :power_unit, :attr1)';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

foreach($products as $product){
    $params = [
        ":unique"=>$product["unique"],
        ":name"=>$product["name"],
        ":type"=>$product["type"],
        ":power_unit"=>$product["powerUnit"],
        ":attr1"=>$product["Other attribute 1"]
    ];
    var_dump($product);
    $stmt->execute($params);
}

?>
</pre>
```

Comment: @Mole_LR Great! Glad I could help!

Comment: just 1 thing that I understood wrongly from html source - in fact image alt for some products can be not the 'unique' string (somehow it can be different for somes)! So, how we could solve this issue for getting image src, because " $productImageQuery = sprintf("//img[@alt='%s']/@src",$product["sku"]);" not working in reality. We could use parent a element title for that...

Comment: ok, solved it: $productImageQuery = sprintf("//a[@title='%s']/div/div/img/@src",$product["sku"]);

Comment: @Mole_LR Ah, now that was good of you to catch, and a good adjustment.

Comment: @Mole_LR Please remember to accept and up-vote correct answers, and up-vote helpful answers and comments.

Comment: Overall I've polished provided ideas, improvded and adjusted my needs and set up scrapping and importing data and it works fine except 1 problem - if string in xpatch query contains less (<) symbol, it cuts this string up to this symbol and donn't scrap full text... Let's say, in <p> element there is string value "Some value (<2m) I need" but it scraps just "Some value ("... Is there any workaround for this? Or better I should create new  thread here (but this problem is associated with this thread)!

Comment: @Mole_LR Is there always a space after the `<`? If so you could try to replace all occurrences with the `&lt;` entity instead? Just use `preg_replace("/\s<\s/","&lt;",...` to get all less than signs with a space before and after converted to html entities.

Comment: I tried to replace in such way: $product['type_unit'] = str_replace(array("<", ">"), array("squarebracketsopen", "squarebracketsclose"), $productTypeNodes[0]->nodeValue) . Because I need some "special" string to replace it after... But as I'm scarpping from existing url (not html that I can change) in this step it does not work because string is not fetched, it already stops before <, so - nothing to replace...

Comment: And yes, there is a space (maybe some have no space, as there are >20000 products which I can not check all, but from which I checked there is space after <....

Comment: @Mole_LR Can you fetch the entire html of each product, store in a big string, replace the chars, then do the xpath?

Comment: yes, this "workaround" works - saving external web site sourcewith file_get_contents, then then write it on the local file and in this writing process replace necessary strings! And then use this local file for XPath...

Comment: @Mole_LR plus! You have offline copy to work on so you do not gave to spam them when trying new patterns ;)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do to make it easier, is when using XPath, you can use one node as the context of further searches, so once you have a list of product nodes, use this as a point at which you extract the other data.

Just as an example...

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

$products = [];

$data = $xpath->query("//div[@class='single_product']");
foreach ($data as $item) {
$name = $xpath->evaluate('string(descendant::div[@data-field="description_detail"]/h3/a/@title)'
        ,$item);

$imageName =  $xpath->evaluate('string(descendant::div[@data-section="featured_image"]//img/@src)'
        ,$item);
$typePower = $xpath->evaluate('string(descendant::div[@data-field="description_detail"]/a/p/text())'
        ,$item);
$description = $xpath->evaluate('string(descendant::div[@data-field="description"]/a)'
        ,$item);

    $products[$name] = array( "image" => $imageName,
            "typePower" => $typePower,
            "description" => $description
    );
}

print_r($products);
```

Note the second parameter to the `evaluate()` method which is the node from the first `query()`.

I've also used `evaluate` which allows me to return the node as a string straight away without any further conversion (it allows me to use `string()` as part of the query).

There is no post processing, so you may have to tidy up some of the data and there is no database access (you should follow the examples of using prepared statements), but this shows the important part of extracting the data in the first place.

Comment: Ah, forgot about evaluate... That would have made my life a lot simpler in my answer above... lol

Comment: While this code is shorter than the one which provided Canis, but it  does not loop throught all 'single_product' elements and just returns info for the first product...

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't tested that.  I've updated the code.  Instead of using `//` for the start of retrieving the sub data in the XPath, I should have used `descendant::` which ensures it only looks in child XML entities.  It was looking at both records, but always finding the first records data.